# Selenium can't click element because other element obscures it

Tags: python, selenium, element

**Set-up**

I'm using Python 3.x and Selenium to fill out a query field and subsequently click the search button,

```
# element containing the product search bar and buttons
search_area = el_id('Products').find_element_by_class_name('searchArea')

# insert name of file to be duplicated
name_field = search_area.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']")
name_field.clear()
name_field.send_keys('to_be_duplicated')  

# click search button
search_area.find_element_by_xpath('span/a[1]').click()
```

where `el_id(x) = browser.find_element_by_id(x)`.

---

**Problem**

Executing the code above gives the following error,

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Element <a class="button button-fleft searchButton" href="#"> is not clickable at point (577.6166763305664,225.06666564941406) because another element <div class="blockUI blockOverlay"> obscures it
```

I can solve this error by inserting a hard wait before grabbing and clicking the button, like so,

```
# click search button
time.sleep(1)
search_area.find_element_by_xpath('span/a[1]').click()
```

But I rather solve it differently, so I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48441919/7326714) and did the following,

```
# click search button
search_button = search_area.find_element_by_xpath('span/a[1]')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
"//*[@id="Products"]/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/input")))
search_button.click()
```

But I got exactly the same error.

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37303115/7326714), but same error.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv)

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB! In the end nr.5 did it! `wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='blockUI blockOverlay']")))` and then `el_xp("//input[@value='Save']").click()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following nr.5 of [DebanjanB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44724688/7326714), I solved it by implying the code to wait for the temporary overlay to dissapear before trying to click,

```
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
              "//div[@class='blockUI blockOverlay']")))
el_xp("//input[@value='Save']").click()
```

Comment: How can you detect the xpath of the temporary overlay? I tried to detect it on Chrome Dev Tool, but since it disappears quickly I could not know the xpath.

Comment: I tried that.  Waiting for it to disappear.  It finished saying it had disappeared, but I still got the error afterwards when trying to click.

Comment: In my case, the overlay is an ad and its not temporary, it never disappears.

Comment: Tried this, but did not work. The overlay slides out for about two seconds.

Answer (score 10):

There are several ways to do this, one of the ways is by Javascript executor.

You could say:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='blockUI blockOverlay']")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", element)
```

This way, you can block the div with `class = 'blockUI blockOverlay'`
and your element can be clicked if I'm correct.

Answer (score 6):

Also, you can try to click the element by `JavaScript` like this:

```py
# element containing the product search bar and buttons
search_area = el_id('Products').find_element_by_class_name('searchArea')

# click element by executing javascript
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search_area)
```

Comment: It working in my case, I think because of call click() in element will do some thing like "virtual click" with (x,y) position, but with call click() use execute_script  will some how call directly to this element's script

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer expects that you know, which element will be used as an overlay. If this expectation is not true (as mentioned by @Blaszard in comment under accepted answer), then you can use this generic function to get any element which is displayed above another element:

```py
def getOverlappingElement(driver: WebDriver, element: WebElement) -> Optional[WebElement]:
  rect = element.rect
  result = driver.execute_script("return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1]);",
                                 rect['x'] + rect['width'] // 2, rect['y'] + rect['height'] // 2)
  if result == element:
    result = None
  return result
```

When you call the function like `getOverlappingElement(driver, button)` then it will return the element which is displayed above `button` or it returns None, when the `button` is not overlapped.

This method does not cover cases when the element is partially overlapped.
For most cases, when whole page is overlapped by loading animation or by advertisement, it works.

Comment: Tnx, it work's for me!